# Ошибка при добавлении карточки

Tags: javascript

Написала функцию добавления карточки на страницу. Сама карточка добавляется, но не передается значение `name` в описание к карточке и `Devtools` выдает ошибку
`"Uncaught TypeError: elementsPhotoGrid.prepend is not a function at HTMLElement.addPlace".`

Код:

```
const addPlace = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const popupInputPlace = document.querySelector(".popup__input_place");
    const popupInputLink = document.querySelector(".popup__input_link");
    const newCard = {
            name: popupInputPlace.value,
            link: popupInputLink.value,
          }
    const card = new Card(newCard,
      '.elements__template_type_default', openPopupPhoto);
    const element = card.generateCard();
    elementsPhotoGrid.prepend(element);
    popupPlaceForm.close(addPopup, evt);
}
```

[image: код]

Comment: а что такое elementsPhotoGrid?

Comment: это список в html, куда вставляется темплейт.    const elementsPhotoGrid = ".elements__photo-grid"; в HTML:   <section class="elements content__elements">
                <ul class="elements__photo-grid">

                </ul>
            </section>

Comment: const elementsPhotoGrid = ".elements__photo-grid"; это просто строка

Comment: приложите абсолютно весь код и со всем js и с html, вам так помогут намного быстрее